# Can I open a shell prompt from within NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, interactive, subshell

I'm in a NodeJS command-prompt session and I want to dip out to shell for a few commands and come back to my session with variables intact.

I remember doing this as a kid using "!" in another environment - can I do something like that in Node?

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered about `Ctrl-z` / `fg`. `Ctrl-z` makes the Node session a background process and leaves me in the shell (and pauses it - if I wanted it to keep running something I could use the `bg` command). Then `fg` puts me back into the Node environment.

This is probably close enough to what I was thinking about.

I'm open to other options though!

Comment: Obviously, Ctl-Z/fg only works if you're in a *nix environment (like Linux).  Another option might be [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html): https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/.

Comment: @paulsm4 that’s true and the article you linked is awesome but I was looking for a “built-in” command, not a programming sub-project.